# How to fill the 'opposite' shape on canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

Say I have a circle (an arc) on HTML5 canvas. I can just fill it like this:

```
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

It works a treat. However, how can one fill the opposite area? Now it's white with a black circle, but I'd like it to be along the lines of the following image (on which white is the background color and black is the filling color):

[image: opposite area]

I know I could just use a black background and paint a white circle, but the background can be anything (all kinds of things have been drawn there before, so just swapping colors is not possible).

Another thing is that not the complete canvas should be filled, but rather a square with an circle canceled out.

I was thinking of a [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/6_1_canvas_composite.html) but it does not seem to fit my needs as none of them act according to what I need.

So, how can I accomplish filling the 'opposite' area like in the example image?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do that using another canvas as mask :

```js
// This is the canvas where you want to draw
var canvas = document.getElementById('your-canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// I'll use a skyblue background that covers everything
// Just to demonstrate
ctx.fillStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Create a canvas that we will use as a mask
var maskCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// Ensure same dimensions
maskCanvas.width = canvas.width;
maskCanvas.height = canvas.height;
var maskCtx = maskCanvas.getContext('2d');

// This color is the one of the filled shape
maskCtx.fillStyle = "black";
// Fill the mask
maskCtx.fillRect(0, 0, maskCanvas.width, maskCanvas.height);
// Set xor operation
maskCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
// Draw the shape you want to take out
maskCtx.arc(30, 30, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
maskCtx.fill();

// Draw mask on the image, and done !
ctx.drawImage(maskCanvas, 0, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id="your-canvas">
```

[Demo here](http://rendera.heroku.com/usercode/0380afa796f5e8bd191700c82cab65bc68c48a64).

Comment: Thanks alot, but in your demo it's cyan-colored rather than white. Do you perhaps experience the same thing?

Comment: Yes, I've used this color intentionally. It's the background color.

Comment: Heandel: Oops, I'm sorry. That was obviously the `skyblue` you used... It works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: I would like to make emphasize the fact you're setting to `xor` *after* filling the canvas. I was setting it in the beginning and filling with `xor`, but this was slow.

Comment: An improvement on my last comment (now deleted): http://dev.rgraph.net/tests/2012-11-30/clip.html

Answer (score 60):

Draw the black shape in the OP-- that is, draw a rectangle with a circle cut out of the middle.

First call beginPath(); then draw the circle clockwise; then draw the rectangle counter-clockwise (or vice versa); and finally fill().

```js
var ctx = $('#cv').get(0).getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 200, 100, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.rect(400, 0, -400, 400);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="cv"></canvas>
```

It might not be obvious from most of the documentation out there but you can combine multiple subpaths in a single fill(), stroke() or clip() operation.  To make a hole in a shape, you just draw the shape of the hole in the opposite direction.  The beginPath() method resets the current path.  For fill() and clip(), Canvas uses the non-zero winding number rule-- if you read up on that it should become clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered this. With a "counter-clockwise rectangle" am I correct in saying that you mean one negative dimension? After reading about the winding number rule, the idea I got is that an even number of negative dimensions compensates each pair. I ended up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/685/.

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful for the HTML5 canvas implementation in Ejecta which appears to require doing this clockwise/counterclockwise business with paths to "knock out" a circle.  Browsers are a lot more forgiving.

Comment: This is a great simple solution, and IMO it should be the accepted answer here. cc @pimvdb

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall i encountered the same problem, the fix is to specify an even-odd fill, like so: ctx.fill("evenodd");

Comment: @eskimomatt Oh interesting, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: To make it simpler, you can use the last argument of the arc function and set it to true.

Comment: It's worth noting if anyone comes across this in the future that 200,200 in ctx.arc refer to half of the width and half of the height of the rect. And in the rect, since it's a little confusing because this was a square, the first 400 is the width of the outer rectangle, the -400 is the width negated, and the last 400 is the height.

Answer (score 5):

The way this would typically be done is with a "clipping region", where you make an area mask for which the drawing operations apply.  HTML5 canvas has the ability to make a clipping mask that is the circle itself...

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/

...but it lacks the subtract() operation that's in Google Gears Canvas, which I spotted and they claimed is "from HTML5"...but apparently it is not.

Someone answered how to invert a clip() here, but it involves an off-screen canvas:

[Canvas 'Clip' reverse action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821679/canvas-clip-reverse-action)

Hopefully someone else will have a better suggestion.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

Using the XOR function on a canvas mask only works with opaque fills (i.e. not compatible with globalAlpha). One way around this is to use the .clip() function and filling the clipped region with what you had in the background. Then, you can overlay the clipped region on top of the original canvas, on which you performed whatever fill you needed to.