# Draw opposite of shape in PApplet

Tags: java, drawing, processing

Is there a way to fall an entire canvas, except for a shape. For example, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271419/how-to-fill-the-opposite-shape-on-canvas), but in Java's Processing PApplet.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Crossposted? http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/2813/papplet-fill-all-but-shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the answer in `HTML 5` linked, I assume you need something like this:

```
PGraphics mask, filler;
int x;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);

  // initial bg color, the white circle...
  background(255);

  //init both PGraphics
  mask = createGraphics(width, height);
  filler = createGraphics(width, height);

  // draw a circle as a mask
  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.background(255);
  mask.noStroke();
  mask.fill(0);
  mask.ellipse(width/2, height/2, 200, 200);
  mask.endDraw();
}

void draw(){

  // a changing bg 
  x = (x+1)%255;
  background(x);

  //dinamiaclly draw random rects
  filler.beginDraw();
  filler.noStroke();
  filler.fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  filler.rect(random(width), random(height), random(5,40), random(5,40));
  filler.endDraw();

  // get an imge out ofthis...
  PImage temp = filler.get();

  //mask image
  temp.mask(mask);

  //dispay it
  image(temp, 0, 0);
}

void mousePressed(){

  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.background(0);
  mask.noStroke();
  mask.fill(255);
  mask.ellipse(width/2, height/2, 200, 200);
  mask.endDraw();
}

void mouseReleased(){

  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.background(255);
  mask.noStroke();
  mask.fill(0);
  mask.ellipse(width/2, height/2, 200, 200);
  mask.endDraw();
}
```

**second example**

```
PGraphics mask, front, back;
int x;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);

  background(0);

  //init both PGraphics
  mask = createGraphics(width, height);
  front = createGraphics(width, height);
  back = createGraphics(width, height);
}

void draw(){

  float x = random(width);
  float y = random(height);
  float sx = random(5, 40);

  // draw a circle as a mask      
  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.background(255);
  mask.noStroke();
  mask.fill(100);
  mask.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 200, 200);
  mask.endDraw();

  //dinamiaclly draw random colored rects to PG
  front.beginDraw();
  front.noStroke();
  front.fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  front.rect(x, y, sx, sx);
  front.endDraw();


 //dinamiaclly  draw random gray rects to display
  back.beginDraw();
  back.stroke(200);
  back.fill(0, 100);
  back.rect(x, y, sx, sx);
  back.endDraw();

  // get an imge out ofthis...
  PImage temp = front.get();

  //mask image
  temp.mask(mask);

  //dispay it
  image(back,0,0);
  image(temp, 0, 0);

}
```

**example using Unfold maps**

```
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.*;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.*;
PGraphics mask, red;
color transparent = color(0);
color opaque = color(255);

UnfoldingMap map;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600, P2D);
  mask = createGraphics(width, height);
  red = createGraphics(width, height);

  map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  map.zoomAndPanTo(new Location(52.5f, 13.4f), 10);
  MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
}

void draw() {
  map.draw();
  PImage temp = get();

  //red
  red.beginDraw();
  red.tint(200,20,20);
  red.image(temp, 0, 0);
  red.endDraw();

  //mask

  mask.beginDraw();
  mask.noStroke();
  mask.background(opaque);
  mask.fill(transparent);
  mask.ellipseMode(CENTER);
  mask.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 200,200);
  mask.endDraw();

  // without this i'm not getting to call mask in red...
  // don't really know why, this is a workaround
  PImage redCasted = red.get();
  redCasted.mask(mask);

  image(redCasted, 0, 0);


}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Apart from simply drawing an image using the mask, can I still interact with the panel behind the mask? For example, I'm using Unfolding maps to display a map on a PApplet, and I want to put an overlay on the map (the overlay has a non-100% alpha value), except for a drawn shape on the map. For example, the user draws a shape on the map, and everything else (but what is contained in the drawn figure) is covered in an overlay.

Comment: In the sample above, both inside and outside mask are being update. The bg changing grays and the squares. That's o show that you can handle all them independently. Play with it, and you will get it :)

Comment: I added a second example that may look more like what you need.

Comment: Thanks, v.k. I'll keep playing around with it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I've been playing around with it, and I'm still a bit stuck on getting the overlay portion down. I was looking do something like this: ![http://tinypic.com/r/2ywh3dy/8](click here for example). I've got the masking idea down, but not how to keep the map (the PApplet being drawn on) and instead, mask the overlay.

Comment: Do you have some code? How are u drawing the map? That should not be a problem to achieve...

Comment: I am using Unfolding Maps to draw the map. It is being drawn on a PApplet. I would post some code, but there's not much to the map: You inherit a PApplet, and in the draw() method, execute map.draw(). Then the map draws itself on the PApplet (using a reference to the applet passed to the constructor of the map). If you need me to provide sample code beyond that, let me know.

Comment: @unseenghost I think you r using Processing as a library, like using eclipse. If so I can't really help with this part. Anyway I made you an example using Unfolding maps, see if this can help. :) The new code is above, in the edited answer

Comment: Not a problem at all. I've gotten the basic functionality working (the rest is just stylizing it to make it fit with the user interface). I really appreciate your help and sticking with this issue for the past week and a half. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify if you want anything more than what that link shows, so perhaps this answer isn't what you want (but it is what you asked). First, fill the entire screen with whatever color you want, then draw your shape on top of that. Example:

```
background(0);
fill(255);
ellipse(50,50,50,50);
```

[image: image generated by above code]

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I wanted to do a bit more than that. Instead of simply drawing the shape onto of another shape, I was looking to create a use case similar to a viewport, where all but the shape is covered by a non-100% alpha value overlay. Again, I do appreciate your answer, though.